# Change Magento URL in products page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url

I am a newbie, so I would need some help. How do I change URLS in my products CMS? Can't find something in CMS Pages or Static Blocks.

[image]

I would like to change "Versand", but I can't find the source. Someone knows something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be added from `local.xml` or somewhere in your xml as `alert.url` ref name. It's hard to tell from here.

You can also enable `template/block` from `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug`. More reading: http://alanstorm.com/find_magento_block_name

Make sure you also select `Website name` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

This will tell you where that text/link is coming from.

Comment: THANK you very much, I got to solve it through "Enable Pathfinder" and changed it in my template view.phtml